# How to display bottom navigation bar in all pages with a fixed index of tabs in Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

I have a bottom navigation bar with 4 tabs; Home, Loans, Insurance and Settings. The Settings page has buttons leading to many other pages but those pages are not supposed to be on the navigation bar. However the navigation bar needs to persist across all the pages to make it easy to go back to the main pages like the Home Page. Below is the code for my bottom navigation bar:

```
import 'package:bima/Insurance/insurance.dart';
import 'package:bima/Loans/loans.dart';
import 'package:bima/Settings/settings.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../Home/home.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final tabs = [
    const Home(),
    const Loans(),
    const Insurance(),
    const Settings()
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: tabs[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        selectedItemColor: const Color.fromRGBO(212, 164, 24, 1),
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.wallet_outlined),
            label: 'Loans',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shield_moon_outlined),
            label: 'Insurance',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is a picture of the pages with a navigation bar and the pages without: [image: The page with the nav bar]

[image: the page without the bottom navigation bar]

How can I make sure the navigation bar appears and works across all the pages without having to add extra tabs to the index? Edit: The code I have posted works so far for navigating the pages in the index namely: Home, Loans, Insurance and Settings. I do not want to add any other pages to the index, I would just like to display the navigation bar on the other pages which are not included in the index.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **BottomNavigationBar** use **TabBar** it has controller that can be used.
First initialize _tabController in init

```
  late TabController _tabController;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, initialIndex: 0, vsync: this);
    //_tabController.addListener(_handleTabChange);

  }
  void _handleTabChange() async {
    //controller handel tab change by default so no need to handle it here
    //this is anything custom you want to perform when tab is changed
  }
```

---

```
final tabIcons = [
  //  Homeicon,
  //  Loansicon,
  //  Insuranceicon,
  //  Settingsicon
];
bottom: TabBar(
  controller: _tabController,
  indicatorColor: Colors.red,
  tabs: tabIcons
),
```

---

And in body use with list of tabs as you declared above

```
TabBar(
  controller: _tabController,
  indicatorColor: Colors.red,
  tabs: tabs,  //list of tabs as you declared already use here a
),
```

---

---

And if you want to continue on with **BottomNavigationBar** follow below instructions

---

---

It might not be optimal solution but it was working for me and hope so it will also work for you, on navigating use **Navigator.pushReplacement** if you don't want to navigate back to last page visited, and if you want to navigate to previous page on back press use simple **Navigator.push**

onTap use this instead of only updating current index

```
 onTap: (index) {
  setState(() {
    _currentIndex = index;
  });
  goToIndexPage(index);
},
```

---

```
goToIndexPage(int index) {
  if (index == 0) {
    //navigate to 1st
    // Navigator.pushReplacement(
    // context,
    // MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()),
    // );
  } else if (index == 1) {
    //navigate to 2nd page
    // Navigator.pushReplacement(
    // context,
    // MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Loan()),
    // );
  } else if (index == 2) {
    //navigate to 3rd page
  } else if (index == 3) {
    //navigate to 4th page
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used your answer by adding `
 onTap: (index) {
  setState(() {
    _currentIndex = index;
  });
  goToIndexPage(index);
},
goToIndexPage(int index) {
  if (index == 0) {
   
    // Navigator.pushReplacement(
    // context,
    // MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()),
    // );
  } else if (index == 1) {
    
    // Navigator.pushReplacement(
    // context,
    // MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Loan()),
    // );
  } else if (index == 2) {
    
  } else if (index == 3) {
    
  }
}` but it is not giving the solution I require

Comment: Can you please tell further what was the issue, or how it didn't worked for you. There were some sort of  error of you didn't get functionality that you want

Answer (score 0):

1 - Take a look at this package: https://pub.dev/packages/google_nav_bar.
2 - check that your bottom nav is implemented in the right place.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by the right place. I am currently using it as a separate widget and then using it as an gate of sorts to the rest of the pages; on clicking login button, it goes to the page with the navigator bar which is the code I have posted above.